# Открытие доступа к разделам сайта после оплаты на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте, есть такая задача: на сайте на Word Press есть записи с галереями и видео. Пользователь заходит на сайт и может ознакомиться только с миниатюрами, полное видео и все фотографии из галереи доступны только после оплаты через Pay Pal. Подскажите, как реализовать такой функционал - когда пользователь покупает подписку на определенное время через Pay Pal, ему открывается полная запись для просмотра и точно также на некоторых страницах можно полностью просмотреть видео? Ранее реализовавывал отдельно просто оплату через Pay Pal и ограничение доступа специальным плагином. Интересует алгоритм действий в данной задачи. Не могу понять с какой стороны подойти, чтобы проще всего реализовать такой функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Страницы с записями выводятся с помощью шаблонов. В вашем случае галереи и видео - скорее всего, пользовательские типы записей (WordPress custom posts). Такие пользовательские типы выводятся шаблонами вида single-gallery.php. Подробнее об иерархии шаблонов WordPress можно почитать [тут](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

В файле шаблона, например, single-gallery.php, вам надо предусмотреть проверку имени пользователя, который залогинен, и статус оплаты его подписки. Если подписка неактивна - не выводить контент.

Comment: А если на сайте не предусмотрена авторизация? Любой пользователь заходит и может оформить подписку без регистрации. Без привязки к аккаунту пользователя к чему-то можно в данной ситуации проверку привязать ?

Comment: Не авторизация, а идентификация необходима. Интересно, а как вы собираетесь отличать пользователей без идентификации? Сегодня он из Москвы к вам на сайт пришел, а завтра из Вены. Вы посмотрите вокруг - и попробуйте увидеть хоть один сервис в сети, который требует оплату, но при этом не требует идентификации. И не важно что это - логин/пароль или аутентификация через Google/Facebook/Twitter account.

Comment: Ну вообще логично, спасибо.